# How to convert .dat to csv in Julia?

Tags: julia

I have a dataset with the .dat format, I want to read it but I can't. What is the solution? I tried readtable() from DataFrames.jl but I get the "Invalid UTF-8 string" error.

Comment: We need to know the file format and `dat` extension is generic. Perhaps showing the first 200 bytes of the file could help?

Comment: I guess that's a tab-delimited file or something like that? Anyway it's probably not encoded in UTF-8, according to the error. Use the StringEncodings package to read files in other encodings.

Comment: The files I've seen ending with `.dat` are often straight-up binary streams, requiring quite a bit of knowledge about how to interpret each byte.  The output of `xxd file.dat | head` would be helpful in determining what exactly the format is.